# Android change alpha on Translate animation

Tags: android

My translate Animation work fine and i would like to change widget alpha During animation, for example i want to set alpha `1.0` to `0.0` when translate animation move my widget to bottom, this is my code but change alpha dont work correctly

```
public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.2f);

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    slide.setDuration(6000);

    set.addAnimation(slide);
    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    anim.setDuration(100);
    set.addAnimation(anim);


    slide.setDuration(1500);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    arrow.startAnimation(slide);
    slide.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            arrow.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    arrow.getWidth(), arrow.getHeight());
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            arrow.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you don't use your Alpha animation at all.
You add it to the set:

```
set.addAnimation(anim);
```

and don't use that set, but use only `slide` animation

```
arrow.startAnimation(slide);
```

instead.